# Problem start up dual boot Linux and Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, macosx

After a long work I successfully installed dual boot Linux (Bio linux 8) on a macbook Pro with Mac OSX El Capitan. 
First of all I installed reFIND on mac and this helpful utility give me the opportunity to select to start up linux from a USB drive. After the installation of ubuntu now reFIND doesn't start at first and only ubuntu get the priority so I can't choose between Mac and linux. How can I solve my problem (the Machintosh HD partition is still present and even the boot/efi)?

Thank you

Comment: Bio Linux 8? Seems off topic.

Comment: Try downloading and running the [refind-mkdefault](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/refind-mkdefault) script in Ubuntu. This is not yet part of rEFInd, but will be with the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced to this situation last day. What I did was, I downlaod OS X El Capitan and Linux. Then I create bootable USB drives in order to install Mac OS and Linux. Then I installed the El Capitan and then I installed Linux. Then both two operating systems are work in order.

Answer (score 0):

You xan install rEFInd from ubuntu. It should then boot inyo that rEFInd, and be able to find the OSX installation.

Answer (score 0):

Press ESC at grub menu and type exit to get to the refind boot menu. If you sync your partition tables that may also help. Run boot-repair in Ubuntu if you can't sync them in refind and it will add the option to grub

Answer (score 0):

> After the installation of ubuntu now reFIND doesn't start at first and only ubuntu get the priority so I can't choose between Mac and linux. How can I solve my problem (the Machintosh HD partition is still present and even the boot/efi)?

The standard solution is to restart with the Alt key pressed, then select the Mac OS X boot volume.

This should always work, with or without rEFInd.